# Why can't parse this XML file?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am making an English Listening Application

I need to display the level, name, name of the audio file, the script of the test. I want to read information from XML file: `"dataeasy.xml"`

But I can read even the first element of the `dataeasy.xml`

Here is what I'vs done:

- **activity_main.xml**

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/linearlayoutXML1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#66CCFF"
  android:orientation="vertical" >


  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/textViewLessonLevel"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="30sp"
  android:textColor="#000000"
  android:textStyle="bold"
  android:text="Lesson Level"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>


  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/textViewLessonName"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="15sp"
  android:textColor="#7f7f7f"
  android:textStyle="bold"
  android:text="Lesson Name"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/textViewLessonLinkFile"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="20sp"
  android:textColor="#865521"
  android:textStyle="bold"
  android:text="Lesson LinkFile"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="40dp" />

  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/textViewLessonScript"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="20sp"
  android:textColor="#865521"
  android:textStyle="bold"
  android:text="Lesson Scipt"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="40dp" />



  </LinearLayout>
  ```
- **DataEasyXML.java**

  ```
   public class DataEasyXML extends DefaultHandler {

   boolean currentElement = false;
   String currentValue = "";

   // Array of lessons
   LessonEasyInfo lessonEasyInfo;
   ArrayList<LessonEasyInfo> List;


   public ArrayList<LessonEasyInfo> getList() {
       return List;
   }

   public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                       Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

       currentElement = true;

       if (qName.equals("Data")) {
           List = new ArrayList<LessonEasyInfo>();
       } else if (qName.equals("Lesson")) {
           lessonEasyInfo = new LessonEasyInfo();
       }
   }

   public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
           throws SAXException {

       currentElement = false;

       if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Level"))
           lessonEasyInfo.setLevel(currentValue.trim());
       else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Name"))
           lessonEasyInfo.setName(currentValue.trim());
       else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("LinkFile"))
           lessonEasyInfo.setLinkFile(currentValue.trim());
       else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Script"))
           lessonEasyInfo.setScript(currentValue.trim());
       else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Level"))
           List.add(lessonEasyInfo);

       currentValue = "";
   }

   public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
           throws SAXException {

       if (currentElement) {
           currentValue = currentValue + new String(ch, start, length);
       }
   }
   }
  ```
- **LessonEasyInfo.java**

  ```
   public class LessonEasyInfo {

   String level = null;
   String name = "";
   String link = "";
   String script = "";

   public String getLevel() {
       return level;
   }

   public void setLevel(String level) {
       this.level = level;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   public String getLinkFile() {
       return link;
   }

   public void setLinkFile(String link) {
      this.link = link;
   }

   public String getScript() {
       return script;
   }

   public void setScript(String script) {
       this.script = script;
   }
  ```
- **MainActivity.java**

  ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   TextView tvLessonLevel;
   TextView tvLessonName;
   TextView tvLessonLinkFile;
   TextView tvLessonScript;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       tvLessonLevel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewLessonLevel);
       tvLessonName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewLessonName);
       tvLessonLinkFile = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewLessonLinkFile);
       tvLessonScript = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewLessonScript);



       parsedataeasyXML();
   }

   private void parsedataeasyXML(){
       // 
       AssetManager assetManager = getBaseContext().getAssets();
       try {
           //Get "dataeasy.xml"
           InputStream is = assetManager.open("dataeasy.xml");
           //
           SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
           SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
           //Read XML Object
           XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

           // My
           DataEasyXML myXMLHandler = new DataEasyXML();
           //
           xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
           //Input
           InputSource inStream = new InputSource(is);

           xr.parse(inStream);

           // get the first element
           ArrayList<LessonEasyInfo> List = myXMLHandler.getList();

          tvLessonLevel.setText("Level: " + List.get(0).getLevel());


               tvLessonName.setText("Name: " + List.get(0).getName());


               tvLessonLinkFile.setText("LinkFile : " + List.get(0).getLinkFile());

               tvLessonScript.setText("Script " + List.get(0).getScript());



           is.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
  ```

  }
- **dataeasy.xml (database file)**: I just write 2 elements here

  link here: [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2wF1bx5DDjYRVRyOWktdElRMUk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following block of code will never add any `LessonEasyInfo` objects to the list, because if the first `if` expression evaluates to `true`, then none of the others are evaluated.

```
 if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Level"))
     lessonEasyInfo.setLevel(currentValue.trim());
 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Name"))
     lessonEasyInfo.setName(currentValue.trim());
 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("LinkFile"))
     lessonEasyInfo.setLinkFile(currentValue.trim());
 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Script"))
     lessonEasyInfo.setScript(currentValue.trim());
 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Level"))
     List.add(lessonEasyInfo);
```

Change the above code to this

```
 if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Level")) {
     lessonEasyInfo.setLevel(currentValue.trim());
     List.add(lessonEasyInfo);
 }
 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Name"))
     lessonEasyInfo.setName(currentValue.trim());
 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("LinkFile"))
     lessonEasyInfo.setLinkFile(currentValue.trim());
 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Script"))
     lessonEasyInfo.setScript(currentValue.trim());
```

Comment: great answer! thank you a million! That completely solve my problem